# Adding data to an iterator created with zip

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am using python built-in function zip() to combine two lists:

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [4,5,6]
zipped = zip(l1,l2)
```

Is it possible to 'add' to this zipped object, for example:

```
l3 = [7,8,9]
zipped2 = zipped.add(l3)
```

Such that:

```
list(zipped2)
```

Would yield:

```
[(1,4,7),(2,5,8),(3,6,9)]
```

I tried for example:

```
zipped2 = zip(zipped,l3)
```

But this results in:

```
[((1, 4), 7), ((2, 5), 8), ((3, 6), 9)]
```

(which makes sense)

An obvious approach would be to 'unzip' zipped and then zip() again including the new list, however, this is not practical for my application is I would like to add a variable amount of lists depending on some logic, so I am wondering if there already is some built in function that does this. I checked itertools and did not find an obvious candidate.

If one could point me in the right direction that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Any reason for not doing `zip(l1, l2, l3)` in the first place?

Comment: yes l1 and l2 are created at a different place in the algorithm and I am looking for a way to a generic solution where you can add n-amount of lists dynamically

Comment: Please approve this answer if it meets your criteria: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39125200/adding-data-to-an-iterator-created-with-zip/39125301#39125301

Comment: Thanks to all for the quick answers! This stuff really helps me to improve, I will also look at the other suggested methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way would be to write your own generator:

```
def add_to_zip(zipped, lst):
    for tpl, elem in zip(zipped, lst):
        yield tpl + (elem,)

zipped2 = add_to_zip(zipped, l3)
list(zipped2)
# OUT: [(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

If you want to extend it to an arbitrary number of lists:

```
def add_to_zip2(zipped, *lists):
    for tpl, *elems in zip(zipped, *lists):
        yield tpl + tuple(elems)

zipped3 = add_to_zip2(zipped, l3, l2)
list(zipped3)
# OUT: [(1, 4, 7, 4), (2, 5, 8, 5), (3, 6, 9, 6)]
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot add anything to `zip` function, but you can do it in this way (there are many options):

```
l1 = [1,2,3]
l2 = [4,5,6]
l3 = [3,6,9]
l4 = [10,11,12]
l5 = [13,14,15]


args = [l1, l2]
print (zip(*args))
args.append(l3)
print (zip(*args))

# Using a class
class Zipped():
    @staticmethod
    def add(_list):
        args.append(_list)
        return zip(*args)

def zipped():
    pass
zipped.add = Zipped.add

print (Zipped.add(l4))
print (zipped.add(l5))

# OR using a method
def add(_list):
    args.append(_list)
    return zip(*args)


def zipped():
    pass
zipped.add = add

print (zipped.add(l4))
```

Answer (score 2):

if you have `zipped` but don't have the source `l1` and `l2` at this point, you would have to *unzip* the `zipped`, add the `l3` list and zip again:

```
>>> zip(*(zip(*zipped) + [l3]))
[(1, 4, 7), (2, 5, 8), (3, 6, 9)]
```

<sub>If you still have `l1` and `l2` at this point, just do the `zip(l1, l2, l3)`.</sub>